# Security Exception when Uploading From Silverlight to PHP

Tags: php, silverlight, file-upload, securityexception

I am using the official Microsoft example and [this](http://www.michielpost.nl/Silverlight/MultiFileUploader/) example as the basis for my code to upload a file from Silverlight to a PHP script.

I am calling `**HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream()**`, writing the file over a file stream, and then calling `**HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse()**` to get the response. When I call **HttpWebResponse.EndGetResponse()** I get the following exception every single time:

```
{System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at FileUpload.FileUploadProcess.GetReponseCallback(IAsyncResult AsyncResult)}
```

I have both clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml files in the base directory that allow access. I ran Fiddler and have seen it download the clientaccesspolicy.xml file so it is hitting it correctly.

The PHP file is running on Apache2 and just does a fread on php://input to read the data as the examples show. It is not receiving any data which leads me to believe that the SecurityException is forcing it to abort the write.

Has anybody seen this issue before and can point me in the right direction of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure the webserver/php application has write access to the directory you plan on storing the uploaded file to?

This could be causing it to abort prematurely.